# Getting 404 resource not found when creating conversation in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

Im calling the create conversation API `https://api.botframework.com/v3/conversations` using curl and getting 404 Resource not found

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept:        application/json' -d '{
  "isGroup": false,
  "bot": {
    "id": "1247256255302317",
    "name": "botname"
  },
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "969923753092546",
      "name": "Users name"
    }
  ],
  "topicName": "Test topic"
}' 'https://api.botframework.com/v3/conversations'
```

Im also adding the Authorization header in the request. The response I get is

```
{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should call with :
https://facebook.botframework.com which is serviceUrl you got from the message.
Not with 'https://api.botframework.com'.

Note : above serviceUrl is for facebook message. 
Think that with each social network, there will have different serviceUrl.

Comment: This is so confusing ,Api spec says api.botframework as the uri

Comment: This saved a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `https://skype.botframework.com` for creating conversation for Skype bots.